# rails generate devise:install does nothing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

A have a problem installing the gem devise. I've already run `bundle install` but when I run `rails generate devise:install`, there were no errors and it just does nothing.

My rails version is `Rails 4.2.5`. 
My ruby version is `ruby 2.2.1p85 (2015-02-26 revision 49769) [x86_64-darwin14]`.

Thanks!

UPDATE!

Problem solved, I just restarted my machine. It works now.

Comment: 1) Is devise included in your gemfile? 2) What version(rails 4.2.x requires Devise >= 4.x) of devise is installed?

Comment: Also, did you check to see if the initializer was added? That's all  'rails generate devise:install' is supposed to do...create that file with all the default configurations. To smoke test it, try running a something like 'rails generate devise User' and see if devise files are created for you. If they are, it is installed.

Comment: I do not know what was the problem but I have just restarted my machine and works fine now.

Answer (score 28):

In case this ever happens again, all you would have to do is run:

```
$ spring stop
```

Your generators will stop hanging & go back to normal.

Comment: this got the devise:install thing going

Comment: fixed my issue!

Comment: Fixed my issue too, but could anyone explain what went wrong ? I started with a new project and I had the exact same issue as OP

Comment: @Sumak Not entirely sure but I haven't had the issue again in 3 years! You should be good, the spring process probably got screwed up in the background somehow.